# Recording both sound and video on my screen via my Macbook Pro?

Tags: audio, video, quicktime, screen-capture, microphone

So I learned that on the Macbook Pro, the default Quicktime Pro has the ability to record video from your computer screen. This is great, but it doesn't have the ability to record sound unless it's from the actual mic picking up sound from the speakers literally playing the sound.

Is there a way to get it to record sound regardless of what my hardware volume settings are at (in particular, even if I have muted the sound)? As in, record sound + video even after I've pressed F10 to mute.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [LoopBack](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/).